# Frontend HTML error with Redis

Tags: magento-1.9, redis

I'm facing some problems with the frontend generation when I enable Redis cache. Basically, the path to some static contents is wrong, just like the example below for the logo image.

```
<img src="//skin/frontend">
```

My setup is:

- Magento 1.9.1
- NGINX + PHP7-FPM
- Redis

It was running well for about 5 days, but broke today. When I disable Redis cache, the site runs well, without any problem.

Does anyone ever faced something like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the radis cache is not flushed correctly. You need to flush your redis cache along with magento cache.

```
$ redis-cli
$redis> flushall
OK
$redis> exit
```

Also after this clear magento cache.

After that you need to check code in local.xml for redis cache as below:

```
     <cache> 
        <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
                <server>127.0.0.1</server> 
                <port>6379</port>
                <persistent></persistent>
                <database>0</database>
                <password></password> 
                <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  
                <connect_retries>10</connect_retries>    
                <read_timeout></read_timeout>       
                <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> 
                <compress_data>1</compress_data>  
                <compress_tags>1</compress_tags> 
                <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold> 
                <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
        </backend_options>
     </cache>
```

Also verify your server port on which you try to connect redis cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  My config is exactly the same as yours, except for connect_retries = 1. Do you have any clues on how to avoid this? Should I perform Redis cleanup regularly?

Comment: You need to flush cache periodically or you need to talk with your host about this problem. He can talk host about it.

Comment: I manage the whole server, but I can't find a solution to this. I already dig the logs, but with no success.

Comment: I just recently solved same issue issue with cleaning radis cache and magento cache. Have you check on which port radis is working?

Comment: Yes. The port is correct.

Comment: Have you changed any file permission or user on your server?

Comment: No. I just used the standard setup.